# Bootstrap Table - Doesn't sort updated values by ajax JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig, bootstrap-table

I'm using Bootstrap Table:
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods

At the beginning I have a normal table with some values into it when I load my page.

Until here no problem.

Then, in the time, these values are modified with my JS (with ajax...).

My problem is here : 
When I sort by clicking on column, Table is sorted with values of the biggining values when page was loaded) and not with JS updated values...

Is there a "memorie" in bootstrap table ?

How to update this "memorie" and sort with updated values ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I am going to presume that when click to sort, the loaded values does not get loaded again. Make sure that values get loaded again. Trace the sort event to get to the root